# Python script launched from Jenkins hangs

Tags: java, python, jenkins

I have a python script which launches a java tool to run regression tests. If I run these commands on directly on command line they work fine , If I run this script from Jenkins the java tool will be in hanged state till I close the jenkins job. Once I close Jenkins job I see the tool running.

Following is the command generated from the python script:

```
export DISPLAY=:0;/home/tools/executor/bin/executor -J-Xms128m -J-Xmx1024m -a/home/ExecutorSuites/FWVerification/Platform/update_firmware_polaris.e.xml -r744 <uname> <passwrd>
```

Is there any issue running python scripts from Jenkins? I really appreciate any help on this. I am a FW engineer, do not know much about java and Jenkins.

Here is the python script:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os

class Unbuffered:
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)

sys.stdout=Unbuffered(sys.stdout)

hostname = os.environ['J_TESTMACHINE_IP']
username = os.environ['J_TESTMACHINE_UNAME']
password = os.environ['J_TESTMACHINE_PASSWD']
vapor_username = os.environ['J_VAPOR_UNAME']
vapor_password = os.environ['J_VAPOR_PASSWD']
executor_path = os.environ['J_EXECUTOR_PATH']
vapor_revid = os.environ['J_VAPOR_REVID']
test_results_path = os.environ['J_VAPOR_TESTRESULTS_FILEPATH']
es_home_dir = os.environ['J_ES_HOME_DIR']
testsuites_string = os.environ['J_TEST_SUITE']
testsuites = [x.strip() for x in testsuites_string.split(',')]


localfile = "C:\Jenkins\localfile.txt"

def create_client(hostname, username, password):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        client.connect(hostname,username=username, password=password)
    except BadHostKeyException: 
        print "The server's host key could not be verified"
    except AuthenticationException:
        print "if authentication failed"
    except SSHException: 
        print "There were other errors connecting or establishing an SSH session"
    except socket.error:
        print "a socket error occurred while connecting"
    return client

def destroy_client(client):
    client.close()

def form_executor_cmd(testsuite):
    executor_cmd = "export DISPLAY=:0;";
    executor_cmd += executor_path;
    executor_cmd += " -J-Xms128m -J-Xmx1024m";  
    executor_cmd += " -a" + es_home_dir  + testsuite;
    executor_cmd += " -r" + vapor_revid;
    executor_cmd += " -u" + vapor_username + " -p" + vapor_password;
    return executor_cmd

def run_remote_cmd(client, remote_cmd):
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(remote_cmd)
    except SSHException: 
        print "When executing command "+remote_cmd+", there were other errors connecting or establishing an SSH session"
    channel = stdout.channel
    status = channel.recv_exit_status()
    print "\n Executing remote command "+remote_cmd+" ...\n";
    print "Exit Status " + str(status)
    return  status, stdin, stdout, stderr

def clear_testresults(client, filepath):
    print "clearing test results at " + filepath
    status, stdin, stdout, stderr = run_remote_cmd(client, "rm "+filepath)

def did_it_pass(client):
    ftp = client.open_sftp() 
    ftp.get(test_results_path, localfile)
    f = open(localfile,"a+")
    lines = f.readlines()
    print lines
    f.close()
    ftp.close()
    os.remove(localfile)
    if "Failed" in lines:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    os.remove('localfile.txt')

###########################################################

# hostname = 'sclab-sfmfv-avatar'
# username = 'root' 
# password = 'pmcsfm'

# ssh connection created
client = create_client(hostname, username, password)
#executor_cmd = "export DISPLAY=:0;/home/tools/executor/bin/executor -a/home/ExecutorSuites/FWVerification/Platform/update_firmware_avatar.e.xml -r342 -uSfmFwTest1 -pSfmFWbot01"   
failed = 0
for testsuite in testsuites:
    print testsuite
    clear_testresults(client, test_results_path)
    print "\n Executing suite "+testsuite+" ...\n";
    executor_cmd = form_executor_cmd(testsuite)
    status, stdin, stdout, stderr = run_remote_cmd(client, executor_cmd)
    if did_it_pass(client):
        print "Testsuite "+ testsuite +"failed"
        data = stderr.read();
        print data
        failed = 1
    else:
        print "Testsuite "+ testsuite +"succeeded"
        data = stdout.read();
        print data

if failed == 1 :
    sys.exit (1)

# ssh connection destroyed
destroy_client(client)
```